# Create table as throws table doesn't exists

Tags: impala

I'm having an odd problem with impala when I'm trying to create a table via "create table abc as (select)". Even if it creates the table the query returns 'table not found'
Anyone knows why this can happen?

```
I0126 04:01:36.553565 25748 coordinator.cc:584] Finalizing query: 86456b134c56d5e6:9f58d67400000000
I0126 04:01:36.643385 25748 coordinator.cc:606] Removing staging directory: hdfs://nameserviceHDFS/user/hive/warehouse/abc/_impala_insert_staging/86456b134c56d5e6_9f58d67400000000/
I0126 04:01:36.658812 25748 coordinator.cc:488] ExecState: query id=86456b134c56d5e6:9f58d67400000000 execution completed
I0126 04:01:36.658973 25748 coordinator.cc:863] Release admission control resources for query_id=86456b134c56d5e6:9f58d67400000000
I0126 04:01:36.673594 25748 client-request-state.cc:1100] Updating metastore with 1 altered partitions ()
I0126 04:01:36.673655 25748 client-request-state.cc:1115] Executing FinalizeDml() using CatalogService
E0126 04:01:36.677054 25748 client-request-state.cc:1121] ERROR Finalizing DML: TableNotFoundException: Table not found: abc
```

Comment: Most of the case this happens because your source table `abc` doesnt extst. But i noticed you are trying to create table named abc. Can you pls share whole select statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the schema name before table name and also share the full query here.